# Virtual packages like 'mono-common' can't be removed

Tags: ubuntu, mono

Any ideas? I'm trying to install mono as per these instructions: http://blog.ruski.co.za/page/Install-Mono-on-Ubuntu.aspx

I need to be able to run the second command `apt-get remove mono-common` but I'm tripping up at that first hurdle!

Thanks a lot

Comment: What's the error message? Also, why not just install an Ubuntu-provided package? Also, those instructions are heavily out-of-date (or rather, the version of Mono they are asking you to install).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to build mono-2.4 yourself? This article seems heavily outdated.

On Ubuntu Maverick (10.10):

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

should get you [mono-2.6.7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/mono-complete)

Comment: ah ok thank you. :) i didn't know it was available through apt. :)